# Why DataInput interface in Java doesn't have readUnsignedInt method

Tags: java, long-integer, unsigned, unsigned-integer, datainputstream

Java does not support unsigned integer types and the easiest way to represent an unsigned integer in Java is using a larger integer type.
[DataInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) interface does provide methods for reading unsigned integer types - `readUnsignedByte`, which returns `short` and `readUnsignedShort`, which returns `int`.

Why doesn't this interface have a `readUnsignedInt` method that would return `long`? Is there any particular reason?

**Clarification:** I'm aware of Java 8 support for unsigned arithmetic. The question is not how to deal with this problem, but why the `DataInput` interface doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Because you can just read an `int` and then treat it as unsigned, which is the standard way of dealing with unsigned values in Java?

Comment: You can do it also with `short` but yet there is a method for this in this interface.

Comment: Okay then that's just weird.

Comment: @binyan That's a really good point. Plus one for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataInput/DataOutput has a method for each of the primitives and String.

`unsigned int` is not a primitive but you can do the following since it was added.

```
long a = dis.readInt() & 0xFFFF_FFFFL;

dos.writeInt((int) a);
```

> Why this interface doesn't have a readUnsignedInt method that would return long?

I assume the original designers didn't think you need one or they would have added an `unsigned int` type.

> Is there any particular reason?

There is so many things you could add (and in my library I have added because I think they are useful) but the designers seemed to believe less is more.

Comment: I understand your point, but why then they did add the `readUnsignedByte` and `readUnsignedShort` methods? How is that different from `readUnsignedInt` from the point of necessity? It makes me think there is something more than just "less is better" approach. But I have no clue what the real reason could be...

Comment: @binyan fair point. It is inconsistent. I guess it's because `readUnsignedByte` and `Short` return an `int`. Though returning a `long` isn't exactly a leap.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but it's no longer a problem because there is now support for unsigned ints. You can do

```
long a = Integer.toUnsignedLong(r.readInt());
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But the question is really not about dealing with the problem, but about this particular interface. Thanks for the response, anyways.

Comment: @binyan Fair enough - I realise it wasn't your question. You'd have to ask the language designers. Since this interface goes back to Java 1.0, there's only a very small number of people who will know. My guess is that they wanted the interface to have as few methods as possible, and you can do without this one.